# How to subset a column of data.frame with a varible?

Tags: r

As we know, it is each to subset a column by a $ sign and the name of a column.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(12),4,3))
df$X1
```

what if I want to subset a column with a variable?

```
a="X1"
df$a
```

Comment: Just do `df[a]`...

Comment: You can do `df[df$a == 'X1']`

Answer (score 1):

```
> df[, a]
[1] -1.7170952  0.4502299 -2.5959374 -1.3582197
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the same output with this format:

```
> df$X1
[1]  0.1591573  1.3328099 -0.2382000 -0.7364309
> df[,a]
[1]  0.1591573  1.3328099 -0.2382000 -0.7364309
```